# How do I count the shortest combination of 0's and 1's from an array of random numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need to get **L** & **N** as inputs, to run **N** as the length of an array of random numbers between 0-1, and to count the shortest combination of **L** 1's from the array, then to print the answers. 
How do I do that in Java?

```
int L = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int N = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
int bArr [] = new int [N]; 
int countZeros = 0;
int countOnes = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < N; i++){
  int r = (int)(Math.random()* (2));
  bArr [i] = r;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the shortest combination?" can you provide a sample input and the output you expect to get for it?

Comment: just changed it

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code, let's see what you did wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Still homework this near to Christmas?

Comment: had some truble with showing it as a code, hope you'll understand .

Answer (score 0):

You keep a count of how many ones you've seen together, i.e. you increment the count when seeing a `1`, and reset the count to zero when seeing a `0`.

Right before resetting to `0`, and at the end, if the count is not `0`, then it is the length of the streak of `1`'s. If that is the shortest `1`-streak you've seen so far, you remember that in another variable.

Pseudo-code:

```
shortestStreak = very high value, e.g. length of array + 1, or MAX_VALUE
streak = 0
for each value:
    if value = 1:
        streak++
    else:
        if streak > 0 and streak < shortestStreak:
            shortestStreak = streak
        streak = 0
if streak > 0 and streak < shortestStreak:
    shortestStreak = streak
if shortestStreak > length of array:
    print 'No ones found'
else:
    print shortestStreak
```